# Why lower bound(<? super T>) is mutable and upper bound not (<? extends T>) in Java

Tags: java, generics, immutability, mutable

I'm trying to understand Java Generic so I ended up with not able to understand why lower bound type can be mutable and upper bound types not.

**The example I have:**

```
List<? extends String> upperBounded = new ArrayList();.
List<? super String> lowerBounded = new ArrayList();

upperBounded.add("A"); // Does not compile (capture of ? extends String)
lowerBounded.add("A"); // Compile just fine
```

So could someone explain me the reason that upper bounded types can not be mutable and lower bounded types can be?

Thank you!

Comment: It's got nothing to do with mutability: you can add `null` to either, and you can also invoke `clear` on either.

Comment: Thank you first of all! Could you explain me then why first case does not compile and the second does?